# Bottom anchor tag does not show up at the top of the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using anchor tags to link navbar to the headers inside of a div on same page. When I click on the last header it shows up in the middle of the container instead of at the very top. 
I want the bottom header to show up at the very top of the container and leave some white space below it. 
Here is codepen https://codepen.io/sasha-code/pen/qBOyBrW
Is there an html way to do it? if not, is there a js way to add white space dynamically below the last section to make sure the header is at the top.

PS. I know this is happening because there is no scroll left. I want to somehow add it dynamically. I don't want to add hardcoded white space.

```html
<div>
  <a href='#top'>Top</a>
  <a href='#middle'>Middle</a>
  <a href='#bottom'>Bottom</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <h2 id="top">Header Top</h2>
    text
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 id="middle">Header Middle</h2>
    text
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 id="bottom">Header Bottom</h2>
    text
  </div>
```

Comment: its happening because there is no scroll left after the last div ... add some space after the bottom div it will work fine .

Comment: @BilalAhmed I don't want to add hardcoded space. If I ever change the size of the container I will always have to adjust the white space.

Comment: its happening because there is no scroll left after the last div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `min-height` of the last `div` section to `100%` of the parent:

```css
.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

#last {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href='#top'>Top</a>
<a href='#middle'>Middle</a>
<a href='#bottom'>Bottom</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <h2 id="top">Header Top</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
   <div >
     <h2 id="middle">Header Middle</h2>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
   <div id="last">
     <h2 id="bottom">Header Bottom</h2>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess this brute forces it. If I had less text in the last div then the one before it will not be at the very top.

Comment: @AleksandraSorokina no, it will still be. Please check the updated snippet

Comment: What I meant is, if I were to remove some text from the last div, then the second to last one would not be at the very top. I know I talked only about the last one but I'm looking for something dynamic that would make sure that no matter how much text I will have below the tag it will always scroll to the top of the container.

Comment: @AleksandraSorokina well, if your last div's `min-height` is 100%, it means that there is always enough space to scroll to the last div (and see the last header at the top of  the container). So if you scroll to any div above the last one, you will always have this 100% space below, and the header will always be at the top.

Comment: @AleksandraSorokina I was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at the end of your file:

```
<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
```

Now it should work fine

Comment: I don't want to add hardcoded white space. I want to be able to change the size of the container and still get the same result.

Comment: Then you can use     <div style="height:100%">

Comment: This works for the last div but it also created white space for every div on the page.

Comment: You should use this in the last div only then it will work fine